# Why does an Apex Action ConnectApi call from Flow work synchronously but fail asynchronously for Platform Integration User

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, asynchronous

#### Background

- We have a dev sandbox that is connected to and receives orders from a SFCC storefront, thus creating an Order record in the SF org.
- There is an OOTB *Create Order Summary Flow* that is record-triggered which will create an Order Summary record from the Order record.

That works.

#### Item at hand

- If I change the Flow to run asynchronously, I get the below error.
- If I change the Flow to add a scheduled path (which obviously runs asynchronously), I get the below error.

**Error**

> This feature is not currently enabled for this user

#### Notes

- Looking in the logs, it appears that this Flow is running in the context of the **Platform Integration User** regardless of synchronous or asynchronous run.
- The error seems to be occurring on the Apex Action call to `ConnectApi.createOrderSummary()`

---

## Question

Why would the ConnectApi Apex call for the **Platform Integration User** work synchronously but fail asynchronously?

---

#### UPDATE 2023.02.14

I did file a ticket with Salesforce Support, who confirmed that there is some sort of internal bug/permission issue. Also, in the February 2023 **Saleforce Order Management Partner Office Hours**, Akshatha Rao confirmed there is a bug, and there is a "fix" to be rolled out of some OOTB Apex code to call. *(My **assumption** is it will be to retrieve whether High Scale Orders is enabled without having to do a callout, thus avoiding the need to make the Flow run asynchronously.)*

Comment: Not familiar with this at all - but, I see an internal bug that matches what you're saying if you can create a case. W-11388471, hopefully they can at least explain it better than I or get it documented as a known issue. Workaround seems to be creating a platform event (or using `OrderStatusChanged` event) and setting a custom field `CreateOrderSummary` boolean you can use in a separate record-triggered flow synchronously.

Comment: Thanks so much, Kris. I came across this while working on a POC for the new High Scale Orders in Order Management. Making the modifications to that Flow as indicated in the implementation guide, requires making it run asynchronously. *Makes me wonder if the folks who wrote the guide actually attempted to implement it themselves.*

Comment: Is it OK for me to reference that internal bug in the case I file?

Comment: Yup - fine to reference it. Especially if the implementation guide leads to this issue.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves: See update added to question. Thanks, again, for pointing me to the internal bug!